# NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED is deprecated

Tags: android

Since API 21 / Android 5.0

The field Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED is deprecated

What is the alternative for doing this? I saw http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#getNextAlarmClock()
But I really don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should upgrade android to api level 21 and your device also should be compatible with that,
you can remove try..catch block also but it is better if in your manifest.xml  android:minSdkVersion is less than 21.

```
try {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.getNextAlarmClock();
    Log.d("Nextalarm",  am.getNextAlarmClock().toString());
    } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`getNextAlarmClock()` is a public method in AlarmManager class which was introduced in *API level 21*. You need to install *API level 21* in order to use this method. Also, make necessary changes in Android Project Build Target.

Comment: I don't know how to use getNextAlarmClock() please give me the snippet

Comment: What's android build target in your project? It should be API level 21.

Comment: yeah it is 21 and but i don't have device with that level and i hope this is the code try {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.getNextAlarmClock();
        Log.d("Nextalarm",  am.getNextAlarmClock().toString());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: try this: `if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { /** use getNextAlarmClock() **/ } else { /** use Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED **/ }`

Answer (score 0):

I needed some code to simply test if any alarms exist, so I can update a graphic on a full screen app.  Thank you to everyone who contributed.  Based on all that, here is what I ended up implementing:

```
private void testAlarms() {
    String nextAlarm = null;
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.getNextAlarmClock();
        try {
            nextAlarm = am.getNextAlarmClock().toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        nextAlarm = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(nextAlarm)) {
        hideAlarm();
    } else {
        showAlarm();
    }
}
```