# AlarmManager.AlarmClockinfo.getNextAlarmClock() causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

### The Problem

When I try to use the `AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo` object to `getNextAlarmClock()` my app throws: **`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.app.AlarmManager$AlarmClockInfo.getNextAlarmClock()' on a null object reference`**

### My Code

The relevant section of my code...

```
public class MyAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private PendingIntent my_svc = null;

    public void onUpdate(Context c, AppWidgetManager awm, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        final AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager)c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        final Calendar alarm_time = Calendar.getInstance();
        final Intent i = new Intent(c, MyService.class);

        // set alarm for 2015-Jul-7 10:35:55 AM
        alarm_time.setStime(new Date(2015,7,7,10,35,55));

        // set up the service if necessary
        if ( my_svc == null ) {
            my_svc = PendingIntent.getService(c, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        }

        // set the alarm
        m.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, alarm_time.getTime().getTime(), my_service);

        // now write a log message to confirm the alarm was set
        // **THIS IS THE CODE THAT THROWS THE EXCEPTION**
        AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo aci = m.getNextAlarmClock();
        Log.v("MyAppWidget", "next alarm at: " + aci.toString());
    }
}
```

### Background Info

I'm developing a home/lock screen widget app for Android. The info in the widget needs to be updated at very specific times other than when the OS broadcasts the `APPWIDGET_UPDATE` action. I successfully followed [this tutorial on using `AlarmManager` to update widgets at specific times](http://www.parallelrealities.co.uk/2011/09/using-alarmmanager-for-updating-android.html), and was able to use the `AlarmManager.setRepeating()` function to update my widget once a minute.

However, I don't need the widget updated every minute, but only once at a specific time that happens every 2-3 days. So I tried using `AlarmManager.setExact()` instead of `setRepeating()`. The app compiles without error and appears to run just fine, but the widget doesn't update when I think it is supposed to. I've confirmed that the correct time is being submitted to the `setExact()` function, but since the update doesn't happen as scheduled I wanted to see whether or not the alarm was really set. That's when I tried using `getNextAlarmClock()` and began having these problems.

### App/Emulator Specs

App:

- minSdkVersion: 21
- targetSdkVersion: 22

Emulator:

- Name: Nexus 5 API 22
- CPU/ABI: Google API's Intel Atom (x86)
- Target: Google APIs (API level 22)
- SD Card: 100M
- GPU Enabled: yes
- RAM Size: 2GB

### Things I've tried

- Logging `alarm_time.getTime().toString` to confirm I'm setting the correct alarm time
- Confirmed that the time of the alarm is in the future (by manually setting the time on the emulator)
- [Solutions suggested by this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333972/next-alarm-formatted-is-deprecated)
- Variations on `getNextAlarmClock()` including using the deprecated constant, `getTriggerTime()` and `m.getNextAlarmClock().toString()`

I'm totally stumped by this. If you have any thoughts about why I can't get info about the next set alarm, or why my alarm set with `setExact()` doesn't go off, I'll be a happy boy. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`AlarmClock` and `AlarmManager` are two entirely different things: alarm clocks are set by the Clock app and other apps via [setAlarmClock()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and are suitable for waking people up and is visible to the user throughout the system (where depending on the manufacturer and version of Android).

That is entirely different from `setExact()`, which only sets a programmatic alarm for your app - nothing visible to the user. You can use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to dump the list of current alarms to help debug whether your alarm was scheduled correctly.

Comment: Oh. That subtlety in the docs was lost on me. `adb shell dumpsys alarm` gave me exactly the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the javadoc for getNextAlarmClock http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#getNextAlarmClock()

it says "The alarm clocks considered are those scheduled by setAlarmClock(AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo, PendingIntent) from any package of the calling user." I'm not sure why that's the case but since you're using setExact my guess is that's why it's null when you call getNextAlarmClock.

Comment: For some reason, it can be completely reset when you remove the app from recent tasks: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150080941 , and it occurs on both emulators and Android devices, ever since API 21 (and maybe even before). Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

getNextAlarmClock() Is meant for alarms set by setAlarmClock() only.  You used setExact() and that's why you are having the bugs.

Answer (score 0):

getNextAlarmClock() can return null. That cause the exception when you do

```
Log.v("MyAppWidget", "next alarm at: " + aci.toString())
```

Instead do this:

```
AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo aci = m.getNextAlarmClock();
if (aci==null)
   Log.v("MyAppWidget", "no alarm");
else
   Log.v("MyAppWidget", "next alarm at: " + aci.toString());
```